# SQL STORE PROCEDURE OPTIMIZATION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table which has non clustered index on `PFX,EFF_DT,TERM_DT`. The execution plan shows RID LookUp heap cost is  99%, instead of index scan. I want to know the reason why not index scan is not in execution plan, and is RID LookUp is good approach.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID
    ,PFX
    ,EFF_DT
    ,ID1
    ,TERM_DT
    ,RULE
    ,EXP_CAT
    ,ACCT_CAT
    ,OPTS
    ,RULE_ALT
    ,RULE_ALT_COND
FROM TempMaster
WHERE PFX = 'I004'
ORDER BY EFF_DT DESC
```

Comment: While i am using only column which is include in index, then the Index seek cost is approx 80 %.

Comment: try using (WITH (INDEX(your_index_name))) after table name , and view excution plan

Comment: It has same execution plan, index seek - 0% and RID LookUp - 99%

Comment: Is there a reason your table does not have a clustered index? Looks like `PFX, EFF_DT` would be a good candidate.

Comment: It has billions of records and, also it has non unique values, data is frequently inserting in it. For non unique data will it not create performance issue.

Comment: Could you add the sql to create your index to go along with your query?  From the sounds of it, you are using an index that only has 3 columns included but are returning 11, which would explain the `RID lookup`

Comment: You will have RID lookup (I am not sure why do you use HEAP table vs clustered) until you'll have covered index that covers ALL the columns you want to return. So the proper index for your query would be: (PFX, EFT_DT DESC) INCLUDE ID, ID1, TERM_DT .. RULE_ALT_COND

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know the reason why not index scan is not in execution plan

SQLSERVER  is a cost based optimizer and it tries to choose a good plan in reasonable amount of time..

> is RID LookUp is good approach

RID lookup is not always a good approach,since RID lookups are random seeks and they affect IO activity..

I would not worry if this query executes once a day..If this query is more frequent,i would avoid rid looup by including those columns in nonclustered index as well

Comment: Thank You, I got my answer.